# Update error with same column type

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have a table that I want to update one column value:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET [Value] = t2.[Value]
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
```

table1 (table) and table2 (view) are identical in structure.

When I run the following update above I get:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I have checked if the colum values are different by running the following query:

```
SELECT 
c.name 'Column Name',
t.Name 'Data type',
c.max_length 'Max Length',
c.precision ,
c.scale ,
c.is_nullable,
ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM    
sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('table1') --and the same for table2
```

Getting same data type, max length etc. with same results.

So why am I getting this error?

I have checked [NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188791.aspx)
But not really fond about it... Any other solutions?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the tables? That error seems like you are performing a mathematical operation on 2 numerics and overflowing numeric.

Comment: maybe I am wrong, but where is your table1 and table2 structure?? your select with `c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('table1')` just selects something with object_id equal table1, but it is not showing us the structure of table1 !? am I wrong? maybe you mean that this select from `sys` table shows the structure on your screen, but we can't see that

Answer (score 0):

Does adding the ROUND function around t2.Value with a precision of 10 change anything? The actual precision would depend on the column definition.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET [Value] = ROUND(t2.[Value], 10)
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON (t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Would like to see the CREATE TABLE statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the precision of hte numeric fields.

Each numeric field is generally defined with two parameters as in: `numeric(5,2)`

What that means is that:

a) the field value is numeric
b) there are a total of 5 numbers that can be in that field
c) 2 of those numbers are reserved for AFTER the decimal

If you are updating a numeric field that is `numeric(5,2)` with a field that is `numeric(7,2)` then it might cause the issue.